# How to load full and same shell from SSH as from manual login?

Tags: bash, ssh

I'm trying to execute some command via `ssh` in Ubuntu

```sh
ssh -l root -p $SERVER_PORT $SERVER_HOST /apps/my-app/run.sh
```

Where the content of `run.sh` is (starting Ruby on Rails server)

```sh
bundle exec rails server -p 80 -e production
```

It works when I login manually and run `run.sh`, it fails when I try it via `ssh`. Because shell uses some virtual path of `ruby` (have no idea how it does that, somehow it's loaded when I log in manually).

Is there a way to make it work? How can I tell `ssh` do keep exactly the same environment as when I log manually?

P.S.

I tried loading environment manually, it's not working, I tried changing script to the following:

```
. /etc/profile
. ~/.bashrc
bundle exec rails server -p 80 -e production
```

Comment: Better not to do that. If you make noninteractive shells load your dotfiles, scripts can break unpredictably when you make changes to your interactive settings that aren't supposed to affect them.

Comment: BTW, `/etc/profile` and `~/.bashrc` is not the full set; there's also `~/.bash_profile`.

Comment: To get _complete_ parity (where `echo "$-"` contains both `l` and `i` flags, signaling that it's both a login shell and an interactive shell), what you want is to (1) not pass any command on your shell's command line, and (2) have a TTY present. But, to repeat myself, it's a bad idea.

Comment: ...you can also just manually start `bash -li` to set the login and interactive flags regardless of whether `isatty()` is true (though your dotfiles can test whether their stdin and stdout is to a TTY and diverge between the cases of their own volition, if they choose).

Comment: ...all the above said, why are you starting a service over ssh _at all_? If you use a service manager like systemd (which almost every Linux distro does out-of-the-box these days), tell it to do the work for you -- then the environment your service runs in and the environment you start the service from (with a command like `systemctl start yourservice`) no longer have any connection to each other; and you can just tell systemd to start your service automatically on boot, if that's the behavior you want.

Comment: ...if you want to know how the environments differ, btw, I'd suggest dumping your set of environment variables in both cases. `env >~/log.$$` in your script, compare the files between working and broken invocations, and whatever specific difference breaks your script will be in there.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thank for advices, I like to keep things simple and usually start service as `ssh -l root -p $SERVER_PORT $SERVER_HOST "cd $SERVER_DIR && nohup bin/deploy_run.sh &"`. Usually it's enough in simple deployments. I'm going to read about `systemd` never used it.

Comment: Which Linux distro are you deploying to? You'll only want to use systemd if it's what that distro ships with (and uses to start all the services it comes with -- sshd, etc); if it comes with a different service manager, the Right Thing is to use whatever it supports (on MacOS the equivalent is launchd; old Ubuntu used to have their own called Upstart, though these days they use systemd too).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'm using Ubuntu.

Comment: Okay, if you're on a release of Ubuntu from recent years, systemd is indeed what it uses. https://askubuntu.com/questions/900389/upstart-to-systemd is an example Q&A entry over on our sister site Ask Ubuntu describing how to translate a service description from Upstart over to systemd.